# Hash sum mismatch error; can't connect to VPN

Tags: networking

I'm using Backbox Linux 4.3 on my laptop. Whenever I try to update my OS with `sudo apt-get update`, it always fails with the "Hash Sum mismatch" error. I tried to update with different mirrors, run `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*`, use Ethernet connection instead of Wi-Fi, even reinstall Backbox but none of those works. It only updates when I am connected to Tor or using the network from somewhere else.

And when I tried to connect to Avast SecureLine VPN on my phone, it also fails with the message "The VPN server did not respond", but it connects OK with another network from another places.

So I guess the problem is in my network. I tried to reset my router's config to default but it didn't help.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If deleting `/var/lib/apt/lists/*` does not work...
(esp. if you're behind a proxy), **fix "Hash Sum Mismatch" like this**:

Create file
*/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99fixbadproxy*
with this content

```
Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth 0;
Acquire::http::No-Cache true;
Acquire::BrokenProxy    true;
```

See also [here](https://gist.github.com/trastle/5722089)